# If $\sum{a_n}$ converges then does $\sum{(a_n)^2}$ converge where $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_n \ge 0$ for all natural numbers $\Bbb{N}$ and $\sum{a_n}$ converges. Is it necessarily true that $\sum{(a_n)^2}$ converges?

I think yes.  Clearly as $a_n \ge 0$ it follows $(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)^2 \ge a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2 \ge 0$ and so $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n})^2 \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n^2} \ge 0$.

As we are told $\sum{a_n}$ converges to say $L$ where $L$ is a real number it follows $L^2 \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n^2} \ge 0$ and so therefore $\sum{(a_n)^2}$ converges.

Is this correct?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The last edit reversed an inequality...

Comment: You cannot write the upper limit of the sum as $\infty$ before proving the convergence of the partial sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $a_n$ converges, we have $a_n \to 0$. This means $0\leq a_n < 1$ eventually, which inturn means $0\leq a_n^2 \leq a_n < 1$ eventually. Now conclude what you want.

Your proof is also equally, if not more beautiful.